# How to write the test cases in angular if there is a init.spec.ts file present?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, mean-stack, angular8, angular-unit-test

I have a test folder in which there are 3 files,

```
1)nav-bar.init.spec.ts
2)nav-bar.scaffold.ts
3)nav-bar.spec.ts
```

I have the following codes respectively,

In nav-bar.init.spec.ts,

```
       import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
       import { Navbarcomponent } from './app.component';
        describe('Navbarcomponent', () => {
          beforeEach(async(() => {
                TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [
             Navbarcomponent
                ],
              }).compileComponents();
              }));
```

In nav-bar.spec.ts,

```
       import { TestBed, async } from'@angular/core/testing';
       import { Navbarcomponent } from './app.component';
        describe('Navbarcomponent', () => {
           let component: Navbarcomponent;
          beforeEach(() => {
                  component = new Navbarcomponent();
           }));
        it (should create,()=>{
            expect(conponent).toBeTruthy()
        });                 //// I added this test case here
```

When I run the test cases,the karma screen shows 'NO SPEC FOUND'

My Karma.config file,
    [karma-config-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcNuN.png)

```
 [karma-config-2][2]
```

I am confused with this modularity. Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your karma.conf.js please

Comment: sure @Anton Bks

Comment: @Anton Bks I updated karma file with images,can you please have a look.

Comment: are you using protractor along with karma by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Based off a quick look, I think the issue is that you haven't configured your testbed properly:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteStub },
        { provide: I18nService, useValue: i18nServiceStub },
        { provide: PlatformLocation, useValue: platformLocationStub },
        ...
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```

Comment: Anton,I have made those chnage

Comment: The question is in whick file do i need to add my test cases?In init.spec or .spec

Comment: The testbed would go into the init.spec as you have it now